Relationship cache rebuild failure in upgrade to 5.72.3
Upgrading from 5.67.3 to 5.72.3 I get a warning that the relationship cache needs to be rebuilt. Very similar to this SE question, but different.  The rebuild failed.  I then used api4 to run the rebuild and get the following error: (apologies for the text format). I've checked the FK constraints in the database and they appear to be correct. Suggestions as to the next step?
"INSERT INTO civicrm_relationship_cache (relationship_id, relationship_type_id, orientation, near_contact_id, near_relation, far_contact_id, far_relation, start_date, end_date, is_active, case_id)
SELECT rel.id, rel.relationship_type_id, "a_b", rel.contact_id_a, reltype.name_a_b, rel.contact_id_b, reltype.name_b_a, rel.start_date, rel.end_date, rel.is_active, rel.case_id
FROM civicrm_relationship rel
INNER JOIN civicrm_relationship_type reltype ON rel.relationship_type_id = reltype.id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE relationship_type_id = rel.relationship_type_id, near_contact_id = rel.contact_id_a, near_relation = reltype.name_a_b, far_contact_id = rel.contact_id_b, far_relation = reltype.name_b_a, start_date = rel.start_date, end_date = rel.end_date, is_active = rel.is_active, case_id = rel.case_id
[nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (dcmadmin_civicrm.civicrm_relationship_cache, CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_relationship_cache_near_contact_id FOREIGN KEY (near_contact_id) REFERENCES civicrm_contact (id) ON DELETE CASCAD)]"

It sounds like you have a record referencing a nonexistent contact. Try select r.id from civicrm_relationship r left join civicrm_contact c on r.contact_id_a = c.id where c.id is null. If that turns up nothing replace id_a with id_b.

Thanks for the quick response.  Yes, there are thousands of them, which of course asks the question of why?  I've looked at a few and it might be to do with case management

Does this help? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/38243/245 OR https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/40869/245

Thanks @jitendra - I also had that problem in the 5.28 upgrade (I'd forgotten). The root cause was missing FK constraints for the relationship table (& many others). Presently thinking about how to fix that, which is a big problem.
